# Django Queryset Filter on an empty list

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many

I'm building dynamic filters which I pass by GET to a queryset filter:

```
for k, v in request.GET.iteritems():
    kwargs[str(k)] = str(v)
students = models.Student.objects.filter( **kwargs )
```

and it's working for almost all the queries I'm throwing at it. However, I have a related model with a manytomany relationship, Group. So a student can be a member of many groups. I'm able to filter students who belong to a given group using the following:
'`groups__in='+str(group.id)`

e.g. - //example.com/students/?groups__in=1

But I can't figure out how to filter for students who don't belong to any group. I've tried the following without success:

```
groups__in=None # students == []
groups__exact=None # students == []
groups__iexact=None # FAIL not that I really expected this to work
groups__isnull=True # students == []
```

The last version was what I was hoping to have actually work. I'm sure I could get this to work by modifying the top code to something like

```
if request.GET['something']:
    students = models.Student.objects.exclude(groups__isnull=False)
else:
    students = models.Student.objects.filter( **kwargs )
```

So I guess the question becomes, how can i create

```
students = models.Student.objects.exclude(groups__isnull=False)
```

using .filter()?

Comment: I accepted the first response since it's correct, but that didn't fix my error. There's an expansion issue in the **kwargs, and I opened a new question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762328/django-dynamic-filter-failure). Thanks

Comment: Thanks @jammon and @DTing. The real problem with this was trying to pass a boolean in the GET. It was passed through **kwargs as the string 'True', not `True`. Which works when passed to `models.Student.objects.exclude( **kwargs )`, since 'True' evaluates to `True`. But the conjugate won't work since 'False' still evaluates to `True` when passed to `models.Students.objects.filter( **kwargs )`. Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the question.  But I see:

```
list(MyMod.objects.exclude(foo__isnull=False)
) == list(MyMod.objects.filter(foo__isnull=True))
```

Comment: no comments, a down vote and an accepted answer ... can I get a badge for this or sth?

Answer (score 0):

I think `models.Student.objects.filter(groups__isnull=True)` should do what you want. As skyl pointed out, this is the same as `models.Student.objects.exclude(groups__isnull=False)`.

What's the problem with this solution? Could it be in your data? As a sanity check you could try

```
from django.db.models import Count
models.Student.objects.annotate(gcount=Count('groups').filter(gcount__gt=0)
```

which should yield the same results.

And:
If you take untrustworthy data from the client and feed them unchecked into your query, you should double check that you don't open a security hole that way (or that security is not a concern with your data).

Comment: missing parenthese in annotate but edits should be more than 6 characters

Answer (score 0):

```
students = models.Student.objects.filter(groups=None)
```

Here is an example from some code i have lying around:

```
# add collaborator with no organizations
>>> john = Collaborator(first_name='John', last_name='Doe')                        
>>> john.save()
>>> john.organizations.all()
[]

# add another collaborator with no organizations
>>> jane = Collaborator(first_name='Jane', last_name='Doe')
>>> jane.save()
>>> jane.organizations.all()
[]

# filter for collaborators with no collaborators
>>> collabs_with_no_orgs = Collaborator.objects.filter(organizations=None)
>>> collabs_with_no_orgs
[<Collaborator: John Doe>, <Collaborator: Jane Doe>]

# add organization to collaborator
>>> jane.organizations = [Organization.objects.all()[0]]
>>> jane.save()
>>> jane.organizations.all()
[<Organization: organization 1>]

# filter for collaborators with no organizations
>>> collabs_with_no_orgs = Collaborator.objects.filter(organizations=None)
>>> collabs_with_no_orgs
[<Collaborator: John Doe>]
```